# ms crm 2015 - set id of entities from jscript onsave

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I need to sync entities from `Ms Dynamics Crm 2015 - On Premise` to my 3rd party application, for this I have set a JavaScript function on the OnSave event of the Entites( eg. account) I can access all of the attributes and send them to my webservice, but the Id (GuId) of the entity!
how can I access the Id (or set it manually) on this event?!

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("accountid")` or `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("id")` both return null, so I can not setValue using them.

Also `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()` returns `""` which is probably logical, since Object has not been inserted in the db yet, this is the reason which makes inserting a runtime generated guid for the entety seems doable !

P.S.
I know I can do same thing with plugins, which I have gone through, but the problem there is that when I register my plugin for `Update` message it gets called a lot of times, (mostly when it has been set for `invoice`), this is the reason that made me go with the JScript, since the `OnSave` Event seems more logical than the `Update` Message of the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, records which have not yet been saved have no ID. That's by design (and obvious).

Also, IDs being PKs in the database, they are handled by the system and cannot be touched or hand-crafted.

Your best bet to keep a similar behavior would be a `Post-Operation Create` plugin living outside the sandbox (`Isolation mode: None`).

Another good option would be to pull data instead of pushing it: the 3rd party application can periodically fetch new records through any of the exposed APIs (REST, SOAP, SDK ... there are many options).

Comment: Ofcourse the plugin method would work, but how about the jScript method?
any idea on using the `Xrm.Page.data.save(saveOptions).then(successCallback, errorCallback)` function ?!

Comment: I can't think of a clean way to accomplish through JScript without multiple external calls and/or risking to mess up the data. Scripts just aren't meant for this.